# WPF Span image across multiple listbox rows

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox

I currently have a listbox with multiple rows and if a condition is valid, I want the image from a row to appear and span into the next row. Is this possible? I've tried but the image gets cut off by the next row and goes "under" the next listboxitem instead of going on top of it. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. If a control is situated within a Canvas, it can be placed outside the bounds of the canvas. So essentially, you can use this feature to ensure that your control is not clipped. So, for example, you can do something like:

```
    <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding}">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Text}" />
                    <Canvas>
                        <Rectangle Visibility="{Binding ShowOverlap}" Width="100" Height="100" Opacity="0.5">
                            <Rectangle.Fill>
                                <ImageBrush ImageSource="house2.png" Stretch="UniformToFill" />
                            </Rectangle.Fill>
                        </Rectangle>
                    </Canvas>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
```

With some code-behind of:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public class Item
    {
        public string Text { get; set; }
        public Visibility ShowOverlap { get; set; }
    }

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        List<Item> items = new List<Item>();
        items.Add(new Item() { Text = "Test1", ShowOverlap = Visibility.Hidden });
        items.Add(new Item() { Text = "Test2", ShowOverlap = Visibility.Visible });
        items.Add(new Item() { Text = "Test3", ShowOverlap = Visibility.Hidden });
        DataContext = items;
    }
}
```

And you will see that a 100 x 100 rectangle, overlapping the ListViewItem appears. You can do the same thing, but put your image inside the Canvas.

Comment: Hey, I tried to implement a canvas around my image like you did with your rectangle, but the image still goes "under" the following listboxitem instead of ontop of it, am I missing something?

Comment: @cravie - please see my update - you are right if you use Image directly, but you can avoid that limitation by using a rectangle with an ImageBrush as the fill :)

Comment: wow, downvoted with no comment, for an answer that worked. I guess that's the internet for ya.

Comment: wasn't me :( , I can't upvote yet, need 3 more rep! sorry